# Using capitals in my username?

Tags: 10.04, installation, ubuntu-netbook, user-profile, thunar

During installation of Ubuntu 10.04 I was not allowed to use capitals in my Username. Is there any way I could change this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Adding new usernames in capital:**

- By default capitals are not allowed in **usernames**.
- You can use `--force-badname` to create a username in capital.(or you have to reconfigure **NAME_REGEX** in `/etc/adduser.conf`)

  `sudo adduser <username> --force-badname`
  i.e
  `sudo adduser JOHN --force-badname`

**Renaming your username in capital:**

- To rename your username in capital,first you have to edit `/etc/adduser.conf` and add the following line `NAME_REGEX=[A-Z,a-z,0-9]` to the end of the file.
  [image]
- And now you can rename your username with capital letter.
- Also if you want to add a new user now,you dont want to use `--force-badname`,because we have added a new expression in `adduser.conf`.
- And so you can simply add a new username with capital letter as,

  `sudo adduser <USERNAME>` i.e `sudo adduser JOHN`

**NOTE:**

- However i wouldn't suggest using capitals in a case sensitive OS.
- Use it in your own risk.

Comment: Doesn't adduser add another user? I just want to rename mine.

Comment: @BuffnLore Updated my answer to change your username.

Comment: This constraint applies for group names too