# How to change 'Your Name'?

Tags: username

I'm new to Ubuntu 14.10, and I want to change the 'your name' (appear at the time of Installation) from `hanu` to `Hanu` in Terminal, i.e., `hanu@4268` to `Hanu@4268`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the computer name?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name)

Comment: I think OP wants to change his username not the hostname.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using capitals in my username?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19455/using-capitals-in-my-username)

Comment: None of the two, he wants to change how its username *it's displayed* within the terminal, not to change his *actual* host name or his *actual* username.

Answer (score 17):

You can accomplish this using a [case modification parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification) of `$USER` instead of `\u` inside the `PS1` environment variable. The expansion would be `${USER^}` to uppercase only the first letter of the username).

You can run this variable assignment on the terminal to see the effect:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;${USER^}@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${USER^}@\h:\w\$ '
```

---

If do you want to make this change permanent, you can use this method:

1. Edit the `.bashrc` file in your home folder
2. Locate these lines:

   ```
   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   else
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
   fi
   ```
3. In the two lines that begin with `PS1=`, replace `\u` by `${USER^}`, so it looks like this:

   ```
   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]${USER^}@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   else
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${USER^}@\h:\w\$ '
   fi
   ```

Comment: This method is far less problematic than changing your actual username. +1