# I need help writing a script that reads names from a file

Tags: scripts, text-processing, user-management

My file has 100 lines. I have to loop over all the lines and get the full name of the athletes.

Each line format looks like this but with different athletes:

```
vada359,Valerie Adams,Women,Athletics,AT,new-Zealand
```

I'm having a hard time coming up with a script that reads the line and creates new users with the `useradd` command - but I should only get the full name.

Can you help me on ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Is the full name always in the second position (after the first comma)?

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework. Review `man cut` for some ideas on how to manage the string handling required.

Comment: yes that's the format of the file. The full name will always be in the second spot.

Comment: yes it's a homework

Comment: I hope to see you answer your own question!

Comment: You tagged this with useradd command, why? And why should we help you with your homework? You were supposed to solve your homework right?

Comment: thanks man,  the professor expect us to know this already and this is an intro class, so more than half of the class is completely lost and will probably fail this assignment including me, i'm just trying to do some research to do whatever i can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i don't want you to do my homework, all i want are hints or suggestions on how could i get this done. I do my own work, i'm just new to scripting and it's kind of difficult for me

Comment: Hints or suggestions are not easy to give if you don't have any knowledge of scripting. Instead, you should look for simple tutorials and try yourself. When you face a problem that fails your script, you can post your script here and you will more likely get help.

Comment: @ElderGeek:  Instead of using `cut` I'd rather set `$IFS` so I can just use `read` with a `while` loop to read the file.

Comment: Do you already have some code we can see? Edit your question and post your code, so we can help.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch     Well, since cut includes a delimiter option and a fields option, I would think it would be a relatively simple exercise, but you clearly have more experience in this matter than I.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is pretty much a homework question, I won't give exact answer. However, here's some ideas that may lead you to solution.

Many tools allow splitting text into columns or "fields" at specific characters. In your case, you want to split text at commas, and extract field #2. Tools such as awk, allow specifying field separator with  `-F` option, and printing fields as $1, $2, $3 , etc. `cut` as Elder Geek mentioned, is another tool for such job, and can use `-d` for field delimiter and `-fx` for fields, where x is an integer number.

Having extracted those fields, you will want to pass each one of them to `useradd` or better `adduser`, which is a Perl script designed specifically for easy addition of users to the system. If you're outputing each name from previous command via pipe to `adduser`, you might want to use something like

```
command1 | xargs adduser
```

There's a bit of a problem however - you're going to be getting a string with first name and last name separated by space. Typical Unix username is done as single string, so I'd recommend you send the extracted name via `tr -d ' '` command, which deletes spaces. That way you'll create a user ValerieAdams for example. Depending on your requirements this may or may not be acceptable, so review the requirements.

In addition, as Kaz Wolfe pointed out capitals in username are not allowed by default in adduser, however it's possible to use `--force-badname` flag as per [karthic87's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19460/295286)

Comment: It may be good to note that [Linux doesn't like capitals in usernames](http://askubuntu.com/a/19460/208574).